# Html object container

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Does someone knows how can I change the container for my drop down box?
I have 3 "TD" tags and I would like to move the drop down between them, using client side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to go from something like this...

```
<td id="firstTD"> 
    <select><!-- ... --></select>
</td>
<td id="secondTD"> 
    <!-- ... -->
</td>
<td id="thirdTD"> 
    <!-- ... -->
</td>
```

To this?

```
<td id="firstTD"> 
    <!-- ... -->
</td>
<td id="secondTD"> 
    <!-- ... -->
</td>
<td id="thirdTD"> 
    <select><!-- ... --></select>
</td>
```

If so, you'd best tag this question JavaScript... and get rid of "object" an "container". What you're looking for is the [Document Object Model](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&source=hp&q=the+document+object+model&meta=&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=2911983a5b1aa07d) and [DOM Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_scripting). Given that I've given those `<td>` elements `id` attributes, I could write some JS like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var firstTD = document.getElementById("firstTD");
    var thirdTD = document.getElementById("thirdTD");
    var selectElement = firstTD.getElementsByTagName("select")[0]; // cutting some corners...
    firstTD.removeChild(selectElement);
    thirdTD.appendChild(selectElement);
</script>
```

This is the quickest and cheapest answer, but you'll want to read a little bit more about other DOM features offered by JavaScript such as `getElementById(...)`, `getElementsByTagName(...)`, `childNodes`, `addChild(...)`, `removeChild(...)`, `replaceChild(...)`...

If you want this to happen when the user does something (clicks a button let's say) you'll also want to read about JavaScript event handling.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was searching for. TY.

Comment: Again, emphasis on "quickest and cheapest answer" ;)